# Unexpected “export default” compiled code

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

The following code is not compiled into `export default` as I expected. I need to rename `onClick` to something else, or assign the function to a variable and export the variable. Can anyone give some hint about this behavior? Thanks

```js
export default ({onClick}) => (
  <span 
    onClick={
      e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        onClick()}
    }>123</span>
)
```

The compiled result (using https://babeljs.io/repl/ ):

```js
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

(function (_ref) {
  var _onClick = _ref.onClick;
  return React.createElement(
    "span",
    {
      onClick: function onClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        _onClick();
      } },
    "123"
  );
});
```

while I am expecting:

```js
exports.default = function (_ref) {
  var _onClick = _ref.onClick;
  return React.createElement(
    "span",
    {
      onClick: function onClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        _onClick();
      } },
    "123"
  );
};
```

Comment: Sounds like a Babel bug.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug indeed. Uncommenting the `onClick()` call in this snippet breaks the export:

```jsx
import React from 'react'

export default ({onClick}) => {
  return <span onClick={_ => {/* onClick() */}}>123</span>
}
```

Extracting the arrow outside the JSX code block makes it be correctly exported, so you could use this workaround in the meantime:

```jsx
export default ({onClick}) => {
  const c = _ => { onClick() }
  return <span onClick={c}>123</span>
}
```

But it is probably better to just give it a name and `export {theName as default}`. Naming it would also let you attach `propTypes`.